# Making a fractal landscape look more realistic

Tags: java, fractals

In an STL format this is what [my current landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEFfb.png) looks like. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwi0H.png) is what the landscape is suppossed to look like. I think I know what the problem is, but I have no clue how to solve it.

I think I need to set the Z coordinate relative to other points around it so the whole landscape's Z coordinate isn't between 0 and 1 but they rather "add up".

Don't want a solution, just a hint in the right direction.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Random;

class Point3D {
    double x, y, z;

    Point3D(double dx, double dy, double dz) {
        x = dx;
        y = dy;
        z = dz;
    }

    Point3D middlePoint(Point3D p) {
        Point3D m = new Point3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        m.x = (this.x + p.x) / 2.0;
        m.y = (this.y + p.y) / 2.0;
        m.z = (this.z + p.z) / 2.0;
        return m;
    }
}

public class Aufgabe3 {

    public static void recursion(Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Point3D p3, int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            if (n == 1) {
                System.out.println("    facet normal 0.0 0.0 0.0");
                System.out.println("        outer loop");
                System.out.println("            vertex " + p1.x + " " + p1.y + " " + p1.z);
                System.out.println("            vertex " + p2.x + " " + p2.y + " " + p2.z);
                System.out.println("            vertex " + p3.x + " " + p3.y + " " + p3.z);
                System.out.println("        endloop");
                System.out.println("    endfacet");
            }
            Random r = new Random();
            Point3D a = p1.middlePoint(p2);
            Point3D b = p3.middlePoint(p1);
            Point3D c = p2.middlePoint(p3);
            long seedA = (long) ((p1.x + p1.y + p1.z + p2.x + p2.y + p2.z) * 1000000);
            r.setSeed(seedA);
            a.z = r.nextDouble() / 10;
            long seedB = (long) ((p3.x + p3.y + p3.z + p1.x + p1.y + p1.z) * 1000000);
            r.setSeed(seedB);
            b.z = r.nextDouble() / 10;
            long seedC = (long) ((p2.x + p2.y + p2.z + p3.x + p3.y + p3.z) * 1000000);
            r.setSeed(seedC);
            c.z = r.nextDouble() / 10;
            recursion(p1, a, b, n-1);
            recursion(a, p2, c, n-1);
            recursion(b, c, p3, n-1);
            recursion(a, b, c, n-1);
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int n;
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            n = 7;
        }
        System.out.println("Aufgabe 3: Landschaftsgenerator");
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
        Random r = new Random();
        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(0.8, -1.2, 0.0);
        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(1.0, 1.3, 0.0);
        Point3D p3 = new Point3D(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Aufgabe3.stl"))); 
        System.out.println("solid Aufgabe3");
        recursion(p1, p2, p3, n);
        System.out.println("endsolid");
    }
}
```

Comment: As you know you have to "add up" the value, why don't you exactly do that? The `Z` coordinate of the new point will be a random different from the previous `Z` coordinate. Keep in mind that you might need to cap the values so you don't have too high or too low values.

Comment: `a.z += 0.1 * r.nextDouble() * Math.pow(2.0,n)`.  Similar for other points

Comment: @Progman I'm embarrassed. I think I had heavy tunnel vision there.  
  
  
@MattTimmermans I'm not quite sure I understand why the it works with `Math.pow(2.0,n)` included, but that works very well. (I had to reduce the 0.1 to about 0.003 though)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the frequency distribution of the displacements you're adding. Displacements to a fractal landscape have to follow a 1/(f^b) distribution, otherwise you get random noise.

In this case, no matter what the scale of subdivision, you're adding the same vertical displacement, which is going to result in a landscape dominated by the highest frequency. Formally, a fractal surface is one that has a 'fractional' or 'fractal' geometric dimension, higher than the topological dimension of the surface, but lower than that of the embedding space. For instance, for a 2D surface being displaced in the 3rd dimension, the fractal dimension should be between 2 and 3.

For subdivision and displacement, the fractal dimension is related to beta as follows:

```
Dim = (7 - b)/2
```

With fractal behaviour therefore occurring between b = 1 and b = 3, and the random displacements follow this profile:

```
displacement = k * rand / (f^b)
```

This means that if you divide your triangle in half each time, you have to at least halve the displacement, or you'll end up with a noise surface rather than a fractal one. The best choice for a landscape is typically somewhere around b = 2.

Reference: https://fractal-landscapes.co.uk/maths.html